# Leaflet zoom control don't zoom in or out

Tags: leaflet, zooming

I have an animation, which starts like this:

```js
Window.map = new L.Map('map', {
    zoomControl: false
});

L.control.zoom({position:'topleft'
}).addTo(Window.map);

//add tile layers
var basemapLayer = new 
L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/github.map-xgq2svrz/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?ac$
    token: '.....'
    });
```

And then I am adding feature layers set zoom min and max, and it did not work either. I may hide it, change the position, but when I click on the '+' or the '-' nothing happens.
I am using the default css from leaflet.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where do you set the map view? If you need further help, please make sure to provide enough details, see in particular [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you setting the initial map center and zoom?

Comment: Yes. I do set the map center and view just after the 'basemaplayer':

var basemapLayer = new 
L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/github.map-xgq2svrz/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?ac$
    token: '.....'
    });

 Window.map.setView([48.5822, -68.3678], 11);